# How do I transfer my email-hosting, and keep my domain name?

Tags: domains, email

I have bought a domain name and some email hosting from a company (PurpleCloud).

I want to get my email hosting from another company.  (Fastmail).  I don't care who I register my domain with.  (it's a .co.uk if that makes a difference.)

What do I need to do to achieve this?  Do I buy the email hosting and use some control panel at the new provider?  Or is there a combination of to-and-fro between different panels at both providers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I leave mail at the registrar while serving the web from host?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14824/how-do-i-leave-mail-at-the-registrar-while-serving-the-web-from-host)

Comment: @su' In the other question the mail stays the same and the hosting moves. In this question the mail moves, so I think they aren't duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

1. New e-mail provider give you management interface and IP(s) of receiver(s) for your domain
2. You change MX record(s) in your domain, probably - correct SPF-data for it
3. Add users in control panel of email-hoster
4. Change POP|SMTP servers in e-mail clients

Have fun