# Can I have a webhost with one company and an E-Mail host with another?

Tags: email, web-hosting, nameserver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I leave mail at the registrar while serving the web from host?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14824/how-do-i-leave-mail-at-the-registrar-while-serving-the-web-from-host)

I was wondering if it was possible to use one company (and respective name servers) for email hosting, and another (and NS) for the web hosting?

My email host mentions changing all the NS records for the domain name to theirs, but wouldn't that disable the web hosting?

I'm using cheapdomains.com.au for my E-Mail hosting, and Web24 for the web hosting. The domain was registered through Web24 also.

Web24's domain management panel has a heap of options regarding DNS Zone records, such as an 'SOA' type, 'A' type and 'NS' type. If it can be done, which records should I point to CheapDomains' nameservers? (ns4.syra.net.au and ns5.syra.net.au respectively).

<sub>I'm not sure if I'm allowed to mention company names on here, so tell me if I'm in the wrong...</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need set up an  MX (mail exchange) record on your Web24's DNS through the management panel to point to the mailserver. CheapDomains will have to tell you just what the email server is called so you can do that.

You can leave your domain's nameserver to continue to point to Web24's nameservers.

Comment: Cheers! I was hoping it would be something simple like that, but all these NS records were confusing. I'll upvote when I get more rep :)