# MX record setup to another domain?

Tags: configuration, mx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I leave mail at the registrar while serving the web from host?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14824/how-do-i-leave-mail-at-the-registrar-while-serving-the-web-from-host)

I have a website aaa.fr with MX record correctly configured and working.

Now I'm buying the domain aaa.es.
Can I just configure the MX record of aaa.es pointing to the IP of the mail server on aaa.fr?

What I mean is, can I avoid buying email boxes associated with the new domain aaa.es and rely totally on aaa.fr email server?

thx

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the same `MX` records pointing to multiple mail servers. 
Here is how we do it:

**Primary Domain For Email:  master.example**

```
A - mail.master.example - ip of master domain.
MX Records pointing to mail.master.example
```

Other Domain Names

```
MX Records pointing to mail.master.example
```

In other words all you do is re create the `MX` records in your other domains and point them towards your mail server (a record).  Now this is not only what is required.  Your mail server needs to actually be able to handle domain aliases or multiple domains.  On Postfix this is very easy to set up, but then would be a question for ServerFault forums.

Answer (score 1):

You can get 3 free email accounts at https://www.zoho.com/mail/ which work with any domain name. You don't have to buy another email server. If your primary company is based in France you could get the domain `aaa-sa.fr` and use it as a corporate email domain.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, a lot of websites do that and host their own email software, in which they can set up multiple domains in.

Postfix, Exim, Smartermail, etc. I use Exim (linux) and Smartermail (windows), but I heard postfix is awesome.

Every time I set up email for a new website I validate it using [email authentication](http://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/emailauthentication/) tools to make sure I did it right.