# I want to host clients' websites, but not their email. What's the easiest way to handle this?

Tags: dns, email, nameserver, mx, cname

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I leave mail at the registrar while serving the web from host?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14824/how-do-i-leave-mail-at-the-registrar-while-serving-the-web-from-host)

My company lets non-technical users build their own niche industry websites on our server, which we host. they can currently point their nameservers at their registrar to us, which ends up with them no longer having access to their email if they've already set it up through said registrar.

We don't want to interfere with their existing email, nor do we want to get into the business of setting up email for them through our service. Thus, having them point A records/cname to us would work, but is this too complex for a non-technie user? We thought of having them point nameservers to us but pointing the MX records back to them, but this is also beyond their scope.

Is there an easy way to 'point records' at their initial state? Any other ideas/feedback?

Comment: The other question is in reference to a manual way of separating email from webhosting, given access to their registrar. My question is looking for a procedural way of doing so; without accessing their registrar. Thus, I believe it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Scan their current MX records and import them to your DNS servers when a customer switches over. Users could also manually do this, or else they'd have to manage their own DNS for your service.

But in essence, there's no easier way. A domain can only point to DNS hosts where the records are identical, otherwise some visitors would go here and others would go there. Emails would be delivered inconsistently.

**Edit:**

I'm not sure how your current setup is, but you could implement something like this: `nslookup -type=mx google.com` to scan the mail records of a domain and then you need to parse them to work with your own DNS servers.

This can be adapted to work with your DNS servers.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea. How would i scan their MX records?

Comment: @Phil - See my revisions.