# How to map a domain to a website?

Tags: web-hosting, personal-website, mx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I leave mail at the registrar while serving the web from host?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14824/how-do-i-leave-mail-at-the-registrar-while-serving-the-web-from-host)

I am using Network solutions. I would like to point my domain to a website. I have both the NameServer1 and NameServer2. However, I would like to keep my email routing as it is now. I believe I need to do it through the A records but not sure exactly how (which field correspond to nameserver 1 and 2). Please advise, where do I enter the NamerServer1 & 2 in the advanced settings so that I don't affect the MX records for my email.

Also, I DO have the IP add dresses corresponding to the two name servers.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Personally, I never answer questions with titles of "Help!" and their variations. I know many others feel the same way.

Comment: thanks for changing the subject, you are right it is more effective this way. I will be more specific next time.

Comment: I also seem to understand what I need to do. but one thing confuses me. I got this info from the webhost, two addresses:NS9.WORXXXX.COM             205.xxx.xxx.x
NS10.WORXXXX.COM            206.xxx.xxx.x
So basically with network solutions in the NON advance section there are fields to enter name server for both 1 & 2. But in the advanced section which I need to use in order not to alter the MX records I am confused as to where this info should be inputed.

Comment: Just to clarify, if your add `A` records (as in the linked answer) to point to your host (the IP address of your webserver) then you don't need to do anything with the NAMESERVERS - they stay as they are.

Answer (score 1):

Give the new hosting company all your current MX entries for your domain if you want to maintain your current (not use the new) e-mail routing.

When you change your nameservers at Network Solutions you will be passing ALL other DNS control over to the NSxx.WORxxxx.com servers.  This generally includes website and e-mail routing.  Hosting companies often provide their own e-mail servers and site hosting as a package.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have shared hosting.
You only need to set the two name servers which are provided by your shared web hosting provider in your control panel of Network Solutions.

Here is the procedure for this: http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-in/office365-smallbusinesses/gg549197.aspx

You don't need to do anything else. Just wait for 4-48 hours then dns will have propagated properly.

Nothing else you'd need to do for shared hosting.

Comment: The OP states that they don't want to change the MX records (the server that handles their email). If you simply change the nameservers then this is likely to mess up their email. If you change the nameservers then you will also need to change the MX records to their desired values. (Assuming that their new host and email server are not the same.)